# knockout.js event that tracks every text change inside a input text box

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, dom-events

I'm new to knockout js. I want to call a function every time a text changes inside a text box. I researched a bit and implemented `keyup`, `keydown` and `keypress` but they didn't work properly. If anybody could give me a solution or please redirect me to some document that is helpful for my scenario. And If there is some sort of documentation about all of the events (inbuilt and custom) that are available in knockout Js, that would be really helpful.

To be specific about the problem:

```
  data-bind="value: targetProp, event:{keyup: $parent.changeProp}"
```

And in Js:

```
    Inside parent:
     this.changeProp = function () {
                if (condition..) {
                       do something...
                }
            }
```

It's not working with key up. For simple solution, please give me something that will alert the length of the string that has been written inside a textbox (on every text entered and deleted).

Comment: In knockout 3.2 this is just a simple oneliner. Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25493308/1090562)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also subscribe to the changes manually.

Make sure the targetProp is an observable, and when building the parent, subscribe manually to the changes :

```
parent.targetProp = ko.observable(originalValue);

parent.targetProp.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    alert("The new value is " + newValue);
});
```

---

Edit: for an option binding:

```
<select data-bind="options: myObservableArray, value: selectedValue"></select>
```

in js:

```
self.selectedValue = ko.observable();
```

then:

```
self.selectedValue.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    alert("The new value is " + newValue);
});
```

Comment: Thanks @JoanCharmant, that helped. And can you suggest how can I do similar task on SelectedIndex value update or SelectedValue value update on option binding?

Comment: @accssharma: see my edit. I'd use a dedicated observable for the selected value and subscribe to it.

Comment: Thanks @JoanChartmant, I also found `valueUpdate: 'change'` to subscribe the updated value of selected option as well.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html#parameters) which updates your view model as soon as the user begins typing a character.

```
data-bind="value: targetProp, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"
```

Comment: Actually that value: targetProp is binded inside a foreach and its value is dynamic inside parent. By dynamic, I mean number of entries(targetProp) can be added and removed and I want to track the text of each dynamically created entry. So, I should implement your solution inside parent and I'm little confused how? I understand how it update value, but I'm now confused with how can I track it inside an event inside a foreach parent.

Comment: @accssharma Can you post more details and code in the question? It's not very clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you guys, I just got it done by subscribing updated value inside the parent one that I was missing to do. :)

Answer (score 8):

Or you can use [textInput](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/textinput-binding.html) binding from the latest KO **3.2**

`<input data-bind="textInput: userName" />`

Apart from live updates, it correctly handles cut/paste, dragging, autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate in real time, as the person is typing, you can do this.

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="description" class="form-control" maxlength="255" 
data-bind="value:description, event:{keyup:calcDescriptionCount}">
<br>
<span data-bind="text:descriptionCount"></span> charactors left.
```

ViewModel JS

```
self.description = ko.observable("");
self.descriptionCount = ko.observable(255);
self.calcDescriptionCount = function(){
    this.descriptionCount(255 - $("#description").val().length);
};
```